# Use variable within unix date command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, centos

OS: CentOs 6 Final 64 Bit

I'm trying to write a shell script which gets the date a given number of days ago. The number of days is dynamic and the code I'm trying to use is this...

```
date +%d-%m-%Y -d '$days days ago'
```

The response I get back is...

> date: invalid date `$days days ago'

Can anyone suggest to me the correct format to code this as I'm pulling my hair out and soon my teeth!!

Cheers

Paul

Comment: Use double quotes instead of single quotes.  The shell does not expand the variable inside single quotes.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Quoting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change single quote `'` to double quote `"`. Otherwise the string `$days` will be sent instead of its value.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[matias@lappie ~]$ date +%d-%m-%Y -d "now - $days days"
04-02-2015
```